# Show that if $(a,15)=1$, then $a^4\equiv1 \mod 15$, so that we do not have primitive roots of $15$.

Tags: number-theory

Show that if $(a,15)=1$, then $a^4\equiv1 \mod 15$, so that we do not have primitive roots of $15$
Please help me with this problem.

Comment: What is the notation (a,15)?  Do you mean $\gcd(a,15)$?

Comment: Yes, as the g.c.d. is the positive generator of the ideal generated by $3$ and $5$.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea which you will be able to use in similar questions to consider mod 3 and mod 5 separately. 
You will then find that Fermat's Little Theorem will save you a lot of work.

Comment: Can you tell me what do you mean by separate 3 or 5 in more details please?

Comment: Prove that $a^4$ has remainder 1 when you divide by 3 and also when you divide by 5.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Use the *Chinese remainder theorem* to check that if $a$ is coprime with $15$, i.e. prime to $3$ and to $5$, the order of $a\bmod 15$ is the l.c.m. of the orders of $a\bmod 3$ and $\bmod 5$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\gcd(a,15)=1,$ then $a\equiv\pm1, \pm2, \pm4,$ or $\pm7\mod15$, so $a^2\equiv1$ or $ 4$, so $a^4=(a^2)^2\equiv1$.